# How to get a specific text in Python from a sentence?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the text after 'born' and before ')'  from the sentence

'born July 3, 1962), known professionally as Tom Cruise, is an American actor and producer.'

Expected Output: July 3, 1962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be a regex.

```
import re

tomCruise = 'born July 3, 1962), known professionally as Tom Cruise, is an American actor and producer.'
m = re.search(r'born(.+?)\)', tomCruise)
print m.group(1)
```

Comment: It would be even better with a `strip()` after, unless you want to keep the space after `born`.

Comment: It will search for last ')' .I want the output to be only till '),'.

Comment: @NEHAPATIDAR Thats right. I corrected the regex now to stop at the first ')'.

Answer (score -1):

Store your string in a variable and subset it.

```
s = 'born July 3, 1962), known professionally as Tom Cruise, is an American actor and producer.'

print(s[5:17])
```